# java : get computed values outside loop

Tags: java

I do some calculation inside for loop  and when I println values inside the loop, I got the expected values,
now, I need also that these values will be available outside loop and not only get the latest value.

example :

```
String[][] matrix = { { "1", "2", "3" } };

    String[] y= { "TEST" ,"BUG"};
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {

      for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++)
      {

       int value = Integer.parseInt(matrix[i][j - 1]);

        System.out.println(value ); //this is OK it print me 3 values
      }
    }
System.out.println(value );  //it print me only third value
```

I would like that the value 1,2,3 will be also available outside loop

Comment: What is ``i < y``? And be careful when iterating through arrays: it may a good idea to use ``matrix[i].length`` to avoid the ``ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have access to all three variables. you have to declare a data structure that holds all the values.

e.g.

```
String[][] matrix = { { "1", "2", "3" } };
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
    String[] y= { "TEST" ,"BUG"};
    int a = 0;
    int value;
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {

      for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++)
      {

        value = Integer.parseInt(matrix[i][j - 1]);
        list.add(value);
        System.out.println(value ); //this is OK it print me 3 values
      }
    }
System.out.println(value );
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable `value` outside of your loop:

```
String[][] matrix = { { "1", "2", "3" } };

    String[] y= { "TEST" ,"BUG"};
    int a = 0;
    int value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {

      for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++)
      {

        value = Integer.parseInt(matrix[i][j - 1]);

        System.out.println(value ); //this is OK it print me 3 values
      }
    }
System.out.println(value );
```

But if you need all three values available you should use array or some other containers like ArrayList:

```
String[][] matrix = { { "1", "2", "3" } };

    String[] y= { "TEST" ,"BUG"};
    int a = 0;
    Arraylist<Integer> values = new Arraylist<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {

      for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++)
      {

        values.add(Integer.parseInt(matrix[i][j - 1]));

        System.out.println(values); //this is OK it print me 3 values
      }
    }
System.out.println(values);
```

Comment: You'll need to specify an initial value, as otherwise it won't be definitely assigned.

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare your variable (that you want to use outside of the for-loop) on top of your code.
Example:

```
for (...) {
    //only valid in this for loop
    int i = 1;
}

//valid also after this for loop
int i = 1;
for (...) {

}
```